# counting object properties with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So I'm trying to think of a better way to do this with underscore:

```
state.attributes = _.reduce(list, function(memo, item){ 
    memo['neighborhood'] = (memo['neighborhood'] || []);
    var isNew = true;
    _.each(memo['neighborhood'], function(hood){
        if (hood.name === item.data.neighborhood) {
            hood.count++; isNew=false;
        } 
    });
    if(isNew){
        memo['neighborhood'].push({name:item.data.neighborhood, count:1});
    }
    return memo;
});
```

I would like to combine the various names of the list into a list of unique names with a count of how many times each unique name occurs. It seems like exactly the kind of problem underscore was designed to solve, yet the best solution I could think of seems less than elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an underscore.js user, but I guess [`_.groupBy()`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) suits this scenario:

```
var attributes = _.groupBy(list, function (item) {
    return item.data.neighborhood
})
```

It doesn't returns an array in the exact way you want, but it contains all the information you need. So you have in `attributes["foo"]` all the items that have "foo" as `neighborhood` value property, and therefore in `attributes["foo"].length` the count of them.

Comment: thanks for the answer; i should take another try with groupBy, but I think the above would provide a count of how many neighborhoods there are. I am looking for a count of how many of each value there is for neighborhood there is. e.g. north:2, west:5 rather than neighborhoods: 2.

Comment: `groupBy` does exactly what you want. You will have: `attributes["north"]` that contains an array with all the items that have neighborhood equals to "north", so with: `attributes["north"].length` and `attributes["west"].length` you will have `2` and `5`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better underscore.js way, but you can already apply other optimizations:

Instead of using an array to keep track of the name and the count, use a `name: count` map. This can be easily done with an object:

```
state.attributes = _.reduce(list, function(memo, item){ 
    var n = item.data.neighborhood;
    memo['neighborhood'] = (memo['neighborhood'] || {});
    memo['neighborhood'][n] = memo['neighborhood'][n] + 1 || 1;
    return memo;
});
```

This works, because if `item.data.neighborhood` is not in the list yet, `memo['neighborhood'][item.data.neighborhood]` will return `undefined` and `undefined + 1` returns `NaN`.
Since `NaN` evaluates to `false`, the expression `NaN || 1` will result in `1`.